# Clojure style: calling 'vec' idempotently or redundantly?

Tags: clojure

I have a function `foo` deep in an app whose purpose is to `conj` an element to the end of a sequential collection. The collections are made far away in other functions. Sometimes the collections are vectors and sometimes they are lists or lazy sequences, at the convenience of the functions that make them. Perforce, `foo` returns a vector that's likewise consumed by other downstream functions that may or may not care what kind of sequential collection they get.

It's easy enough to coerce `foo`'s argument `xs` to a vector with `(vec xs)` before `conj`ing the new data. My question is whether I pay an avoidable (and potentially polynomial!) price if `xs` happens already to be a vector, or are `vec` and its callees "smart" enough to bypass redundant allocations in this case?

The [source for `vec`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L367) shows its eventually calling `clojure.lang.LazilyPersistentVector/create` if `vec`'s argument is a `vector?` and not an `clojure.lang.IObj`. At that point in my digging for an answer I thought it might be smarter to ask a question in SO about design intent than to dig further into the guts of implementation that may change in the future.

Comment: I've been using `vec` whenever I need vector specific insertion behavior and haven't noticed it as bottle neck (even in applications I've profiled). I also haven't really pushed it to see if it becomes a bottleneck at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an [interesting blog post](http://insideclojure.org/2015/01/07/vec-perf/) that covers the topic, seemingly authored by a Clojure language dev. The important part is a ways down the page:

When calling `vec` on a...

> IPersistentVector - if it’s already a vector, remove meta and return a new instance. This happens a lot as seen above and is now a fast constant time operation instead of a linear time operation.

Unless I'm missing some context, this seems to suggest that `vec` has been optimized (as of January 2015) to be a constant time operation on collections that are already vectors.

Just for completeness, I ran tests using [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) (Thanks @Thumbnail for the idea). I ran it on a Surface Pro 4, with an M3 processor, which is insanely weak. Expect your times to be much shorter:

```
(let [small-v (into [] (range 1000))
      large-v (into [] (range 1000000))]
  (do
    (c/bench (vec small-v))
    (println "-----")
    (c/bench (vec large-v))))
Evaluation count : 2902458480 in 60 samples of 48374308 calls.
             Execution time mean : 18.612868 ns ; <----------
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.153643 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 17.731625 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 22.199789 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 3.054999 ns

Found 6 outliers in 60 samples (10.0000 %)
    low-severe   6 (10.0000 %)
 Variance from outliers : 46.7497 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
-----
Evaluation count : 3122779260 in 60 samples of 52046321 calls.
             Execution time mean : 16.303825 ns ; <----------
    Execution time std-deviation : 0.614467 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 15.727943 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 17.949363 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 3.054999 ns

Found 5 outliers in 60 samples (8.3333 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
    low-mild     4 (6.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 23.8541 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

The times are nearly identical (within 2ns of each other). This seems to confirm the above quote.

Comment: The code does not seem to do this: `(let [x [1 2 3]](identical? x (vec x)))` returns `false`.

Comment: @Thumbnail The meta data of the returned vector is wiped. Is that taken into account in `identical?`?

Comment: I've got it back to front. If two references are identical (returning truthy to `identical?`), they are to the same object, hence have the same metadata. So `(vec x)` is a different *object* from `x`. How much does it share of `x`'s representation? I don't know. Help!

Comment: Criterium confirms this. `(bench (vec x))` returned a mean of 11 ns, for `x` as a vector 10 thousand long and one 10 million long. Naive timing at the REPL  gave contrary results.

Comment: @Thumbnail Cool, thank you for testing that. To be honest, I was relying entirely on the linked post.